# PHP - Count elements for the past 15 days with time interval

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop, intervals, date-sub

I'm trying to count rows based on when they were created.

Each day should be different but it just returns me 2 days.

For instance 1 day ago it should count 2, 6, 8 (because total is number 2 plus number 6) and so on.
There are date on the database but it looks like after the second look it get stuck.

Here the code

```
$dayLosses = array();
$daywins = array();
$dayTotal = array();
$addCounter = 1;
$counter2 = 2;
while($addCounter < 15){

    //losses
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `signals` WHERE userID = ? AND outcome = 1 AND created_at BETWEEN 
                DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL $counter2  DAY)
                    AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ";
    //counting losses
    $result = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(1, $userID);
    if ($result->execute()) {
        $dayLosses[] = $result->rowCount();
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `signals` WHERE userID = ? AND outcome = 2 AND created_at BETWEEN 
                DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL $counter2 DAY)
                  AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL $addCounter DAY) ";
    //counting winners
    $result = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(1, $userID);
    if ($result->execute()) {
        $daywins[] = $result->rowCount();
    }

    $dayTotal[] = $day2Loss + $day2Wins;

    $counter2 += 1;
    $addCounter += 1;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($dayLosses); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($daywins); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($dayTotal); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Here's the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 8
    [10] => 8
    [11] => 8
    [12] => 8
    [13] => 8
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The output above, is that the arrays
$dayLosses = array(); and $daywins = array();?

What is the purpose of this line: $dayTotal[] = $day2Loss + $day2Wins;?
I can't find those variables anywhere else in your script.

Comment: Hi, the purpose is that I need also the sum of the 2.
I might be wrong but I think the issue has to be in the INTERVAL between 2 dates. This is the first time doing this, and I couldn't find nothing online.